# AWS Elastic beanstalk django migration not working

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-migrations

I am trying to deploy my application using `eb deploy`

I have my migrate file at .platform/hooks/predeplou/01_migrate_pre.sh:

```
source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate
echo "Running migrations predeploy"
python /var/app/current/manage.py migrate 
python /var/app/current/manage.py showmigrations
echo "finished migrations"
```

The deployment appears to go succesfully but the migration does not occur. When I check the logs the eb-hooks.log show that the 01_migrate_pre.sh file has ran but the migration has not been implemented e.g. the
There are migrations that are shown as not ran from the print out of `showmigrations`:

```
Running migrations predeploy 
 [X] 0027_alter_sideeffect_se_name
 [ ] 0028_alter_sideeffect_se_name
finished migrations
```

Please can anyone advice hoe I can get the migration to run (or even just to get a print out of the output of the migrate command, e.g. it is not printing out anything to log like '  No migrations to apply.'

Comment: did you test the same the locally with the same database server type?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the migrations table to confirm this as well?